# Get emojis in a message and getting its "code"

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, emoji

I want to get a message and check if it has any emojis in it.

If it does then replace the actual emoji with the string you use to write them (Ex: `:wave:`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `demojize` method of `emoji` library:

1. Installation:

`pip install emoji`

2. Usage:

```
import emoji

emoji_text = emoji.emojize(":zipper-mouth_face:")
# 
print(emoji_text)

# :zipper-mouth_face:
print(emoji.demojize(emoji_text))
```

Comment: And can I do this for every emoji in a string? Per example: `You can't tell nobody about this ` can I get the emoji from the string and make it like `You can't tell nobody about this :zipper-mouth_face:`?